# Create Regular Expression To Match Substring

Tags: regex, scala

I can have strings of the following structure:

```scala
   MIME type [application/octet-stream] is not allowed for service
   MIME type [application/pdf] is not allowed for service 
   MIME type [application/txt] is not allowed for service
```

I want to create a regex which will match any of these strings so I created a regex like this:

```scala
val p : Regex = Regex.quote("MIME type ([[a-z/]+]) is not allowed for service").r
```

But when I try the match I get an `None` meaning nothing has matched. What is wrong with the regex? I am using grouping to match the variable part.

Comment: Try `val p = """\s*MIME type (\[[a-z/-]+\]) is not allowed for service\s*""".r`. Note the first one has a `-` inside but your `[a-z/]` does not match it. If there can be anything inside `[...]`, replace `[a-z/-]+` with `[^\[\]]+`

Comment: Yes that worked but I thought I could use Regex.quote to do escaping, no?

Comment: No, you should not escape special regex metacharacters that must remain special. You overescaped the pattern making it a literal string pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not escape special regex metacharacters that must remain special in the expression. You overescaped the pattern making it a literal string pattern.

Note that there seems to be leading/trailing whitespace in the strings you show, you need to add `\s*` on both ends.

Also, the `[a-z/]` character class does not match `-` that is present inside the brackets in the first string.

You may use

```
val p = """\s*MIME type (\[[^\]\[]+\]) is not allowed for service\s*""".r
```

Note the `\[[^\]\[]+\]` part, it matches

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[]+` - 1+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - matches a `]` char.